# What's wrong with this T-SQL MERGE statement?

Tags: t-sql, merge, upsert

I am new to `MERGE`, and I'm sure I have some error in my code.

This code will run and create my scenario:

I have two tables, one that is called `TempUpsert` that fills from a `SqlBulkCopy` operation (100s of millions of records) and a `Sales` table that holds the production data which is to be indexed and used.

I wish to merge the `TempUpsert` table with the `Sales` one

I am obviously doing something wrong as it fails with even the smallest example

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TempUpsert]') )
drop table TempUpsert;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempUpsert](
      [FirstName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [LastName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [Score] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] ;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
      [FullName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [LastName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [FirstName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [lastUpdated] [date] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
      [FullName] ASC
)

---- PROC

CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[sp_MoveFromTempUpsert_to_Sales]
(@HashMod int)
AS
BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE Sales AS trget
    USING (

    SELECT 
--- Edit: Thanks to Mikal added DISTINCT
DISTINCT
            FirstName, LastName , [Score], LastName+'.'+FirstName  AS FullName
    FROM TempUpsert AS ups) AS src (FirstName, LastName, [Score], FullName)

    ON 
    (
            src.[Score] = @hashMod 
    AND 
            trget.FullName=src.FullName
    )

    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN 

        UPDATE SET trget.lastUpdated = GetDate() 

      WHEN NOT MATCHED 
            THEN        INSERT   ([FullName], [LastName], [FirstName], [lastUpdated]) 
      VALUES (FullName, src.LastName, src.FirstName, GetDate())

   OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.* ;
      --print @@rowcount

END

GO

---  Insert dummie data

INSERT INTO TempUpsert (FirstName, LastName, Score)
VALUES ('John','Smith',2);


INSERT INTO TempUpsert (FirstName, LastName, Score)
VALUES ('John','Block',2);


INSERT INTO TempUpsert (FirstName, LastName, Score)
VALUES ('John','Smith',2); --make multiple on purpose

----- EXECUTE PROC
GO


DECLARE     @return_value int

EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[sp_MoveFromTempUpsert_to_Sales]
            @HashMod = 2

SELECT      'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

This returns:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>   (1 row(s) affected)
>   (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure sp_MoveFromTempUpsert_to_Sales, Line 12
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Sales'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Sales'. The statement has been terminated.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

What am I doing wrong please?

Greatly appreciated

Comment: The `WHEN NOT MATCHED` etc is evaluated before any inserts have happened if that is the source of the confusion? It is not the case that once you insert a matching row then future rows with the same PK will be regarded as `MATCHED`. This is required for Halloweeen Protection.

Comment: When the Match happens I wish to update the [lastupdated] field and when the match fails I wish to Insert a new record in the Sales table. I cannot pick and choose my input from the staging table (TempUpsert).

Answer (score 2):

The first two rows in your staging table will give you the duplicate PK. violation.  Conc is the PK and you insert tmain+dmain with the same value twice.

Comment: Hi Mikal, thanks for your quick response. I have 1000s of duplicate records in the staging table, that is why i am using the merge statement

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein Merge will only match duplicates that are already in the target table. Not while executing. You have to remove the duplicates in the `using` clause.

Comment: Sorry, How do I do that ? group by ? distinct ?

Comment: You can do a group by on firstname and lastname. And you need to use an aggregate function on score. (max, min ...)

Comment: So I added DISTINCT to the SELECT
Now:
 SELECT DISTINCT
            FirstName, LastName , [Score], LastName+'.'+FirstName  
returns:
Inserted everytime, never updated. 
Could someone help me by telling me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Distinct will only work if every duplicate has the same score value. If no row is updated then there where no matched rows in the target table before you executed the merge.

Comment: The score is not really a score, is a hash function to divide the HUGE  recordsets into chunks so as not to choke the Sql server.

Regarding the Group by, is it better than DISTINCT (I'll take your word on it :)

Comment: Distinct and group by us only equivalent if you do a group by on **all** columns. Otherwise it will give you different results.

Comment: SELECT     FirstName, LastName, Score, LastName + '.' + FirstName AS FullName
 FROM         TempUpsert AS ups
 GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Score, LastName + '.' + FirstName

However, it still does *INSERTS* for everything, instead of updates...

Comment: If you don't have rows in target table that matches on fullname on hashcode that is to be expected.

Comment: OMG, I kept running the script, which dropd the tables, hence always inserts.
thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

In Summation

MERGE requires its input (Using) to be duplicates free
the Using is a regular SQL statement, so you can use Group By, distinct and having as well as Where clauses.

My final Merge looks like so :

```
MERGE Sales AS trget
    USING (

    SELECT     FirstName, LastName, Score, LastName + '.' + FirstName AS FullName
    FROM         TempUpsert AS ups
    WHERE Score = @hashMod  
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Score, LastName + '.' + FirstName

    ) AS src (FirstName, LastName, [Score], FullName)


    ON 
    (
    --        src.[Score] = @hashMod 
    --AND 
            trget.FullName=src.FullName
    )

    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN 

        UPDATE SET trget.lastUpdated = GetDate() 


      WHEN NOT MATCHED 
            THEN        INSERT   ([FullName], [LastName], [FirstName], [lastUpdated]) 
      VALUES (FullName, src.LastName, src.FirstName, GetDate())

   OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.* ;
      --print @@rowcount

END
```

And it works!

Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Without DISTINCT or proper AGGREGATE function in subquery used in USING part of MERGE there will be two rows which suits criteria used in ON part of MERGE, which is not allowed. (Two John.Smith)

**AND**

Move the condition `src.[Score] = @hashMod` inside the subquery,

instead if ON clause not succeed, for example John.Smith have score of 2, and @HashMod = 1 - then if you already have the row with John.Smith in target table - you'll get an error with Primary Key Constraint

Comment: thanks Oleg, at this juncture I understand that. My current problem is that merge is now a complex Inserting system, but it never updates only *INSERTS*

Comment: See what do you provide in @hashMod